# Unable to deploy Azure Function App - error with storage account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

Lately I've had trouble with deploying a Function App via Azure CLI. Last week on Tuesday, I was still able to deploy a Function App via Azure CLI.

This week, like any other day before that, I used fairly common Azure Function Tools command `func azure functionapp publish`. The version of Azure Function Tools I am using is 3.0.3233.

Now I am getting this error every time:

```
Retry: 1 of 3
Error creating a Blob container reference. Please make sure your connection string in "AzureWebJobsStorage" is valid
Retry: 2 of 3
Error creating a Blob container reference. Please make sure your connection string in "AzureWebJobsStorage" is valid
Retry: 3 of 3
Error creating a Blob container reference. Please make sure your connection string in "AzureWebJobsStorage" is valid
```

I checked that AzureWebJobsStorage setting has a correct value, I even connected to storage account connection string via Azure Storage Explorer app.

Just in case, I created a new Function App in another region and I still get the same error.

Has anyone else encountered this error? I suspect this is an error in the tool itself, maybe a faulty build?

Comment: It's not a faulty build, I just checked that this happens also with version 2.7.3188

Comment: Which trigger are you using?

Comment: I could run `func publish` successfully a few hours ago on multiple hosting plans in East US. Build is `3.0.3233` too. Just to make sure, can you run `func azure functionapp publish --debug ...` and see if there's any useful information to help troubleshoot?

Comment: I use HTTP trigger. Even if I publish a brand new function app I get the same error.

Comment: I forgot to add: --debug flag does not reveal anything

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that `AzureWebJobsStorage` is not present/invalid in App Settings section of the function app in the Azure portal.

*Make sure that it is added there and you are not deleting those settings through CLI/templates and recreating them without `AzureWebJobsStorage`.*

Comment: Hi singhh-msft. Actually the value is present there in the Azure portal. That was included in the template. Today, I tried to the same thing but this time creating a single Function app from portal. When I try to add function like before it get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my own question. It seems that this was a transient error. Without changing any code, today I was able to redeploy my function app. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have "Allow storage account key access" enabled , you get this error.

There could be other scenarios as well. But the error does not say anything .